# Automating Traffic to Website

Tags: database, macos, selenium, url, proxy

How can I single handedly create views to my website just using my computer. I'm open to any and all options. It would have to work on a Mac. I apologize for the broadness of this question, but comment if you need clarification on what I'm asking. I want to start off with just basic hits to my website. For example if I looked at my statistics it would go from 20 views on June 6 to 100 on June 6 (hypothetical). I want to create them through proxies, but if there are ways I can get views without a proxy, I'd be open. Basically creating "artificial" views generated from my computer. I can't find a bot or tool that looks legit and may have to learn to code one.

Comment: details to what views and how do you want to create them

Comment: you could add these details to the question itself

Answer (score -1):

You could use Selenium's IDE record an playback
http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

Comment: I've tried to open Selenium, is there a way to open it in the browser or would I have to run it through a shell. Tbh I'm very new and have no idea where to start with these things.